# How to set properties to apache camel groovy script component

Tags: java, groovy, apache-camel

I'm using apache camel script component to call a external groovy file.

```
     from("activemq:queue:test.ChooseIManger")
     .script().groovy("resource:classpath:tests/port/test.gsh")
```

I want to pass some properties when calling this script.
I can do that with simple java code as follows.

```
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.setProperty("INPUTS", inputs);
        binding.setProperty("RESULT", results);

        GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding); 
        Object script = shell.evaluate(getScript("tests/port/test.gsh"));
```

But how we can bind properties in camel router like this.

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/groovy.html) it seems you should be able to overload the default Groovy instance by using a custom GroovyShellFactory.

Something like this according to the information you've provided:

```
public class CustomGroovyShellFactory implements GroovyShellFactory {

  public GroovyShell createGroovyShell(Exchange exchange) {
    Binding binding = new Binding();
    binding.setProperty("INPUTS", inputs);
    binding.setProperty("RESULT", results);
    return new GroovyShell(binding);
  }
}
```

And then add that bean to your context.

Comment: I've defined the camelConext like this.

 @Inject
 @ContextName("camel-cdi-context")
 private CamelContext camelctx;

How we can bind this custom factory to this context. Is there a way to bind this to the router.

Thank you for ur reply.

Comment: As we're developing our routes using XML DSL (OSGi Blueprint) I'm not 100% sure how you would add your bean to the context. It is probably done using Spring Dependency Injection as is the case when using XML DSL.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible in Camel. In method `evaluate` of class `org.apache.camel.language.groovy.GroovyExpression`, all previously set bindings simply get overridden with the Camel bindings (e.g. `camelContext`) instead of being merged.

```
public <T> T evaluate(Exchange exchange, Class<T> type) {
    Script script = instantiateScript(exchange);
    script.setBinding(createBinding(exchange));
    Object value = script.run();

    return exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter().convertTo(type, value);
}
```

Thus all of your bindings are lost. I guess this cannot be resolved without changing Camel itself.

But, if anyone has a solution for this, I'd really like to know it.